# Perl, Alias sub to variable

Tags: performance, perl

I'm currently doing micro-optimization of a perl program and like to optimize some getters.

I have a package with this getter-structure:

```
package Test;

our $ABC;

sub GetABC { $ABC } # exported sub...
```

Calling GetABC() creates a lot of sub-related overhead. Accessing the variable directly via $Test::ABC is insanely faster.

Is there a way to alias the getter to the variable to gain the same performanceboost as if I would call the variable directly? Inlining hint with "()" doesn seem to work...

Comment: How often do you do this that the difference actually matters?

Comment: Around 100k :-) It's a difference of 30-40ms (which is quite a lot for my current scenarios).

Comment: Import the values into the current namespace perhaps? What's the issue with just referring to `$Test::ABC`?

Comment: Using $Test::ABC would require to rewrite several hundred files. So I'd like to try the "easy way" first.

Comment: Well, one of my thoughts would be copy into the local namespace using typeglobs, something like `our $newABC; *newABC = \*Test::ABC;` but that'll have the same problem. Otherwise `use constant;` might do the trick, as that more or less does the same thing.

Comment: I find it curious that you are talking about such a deep down level of language features, and yet you used wrong comment syntax in your code example. ;)

Comment: olol indeed :D *fixed*

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to turn a variable into an accessor sub, or to replace a sub with a variable access. You will have to live with the overhead.

Non-solutions:

- Using a `()` prototype does not turn calls into your sub to constant accesses because that prototype merely makes a sub *potentially eligible* for inlining. Since the body of the sub is not itself constant, this sub cannot be a constant.
- The overhead is per-call as perl has to do considerable bookkeeping for each call. Therefore, rewriting that accessor in XS won't help much.
- Creating a `constant` won't help because the constant will be a copy, not an  alias of your variable.

But looking at the [`constant.pm` source code](https://metacpan.org/source/RJBS/constant-1.33/lib/constant.pm) seems to open up an interesting solution. Note that **this a hack**, and may not work in all versions of Perl: When we assign a scalar ref to a symbol table entry directly where that entry does not yet contain a typeglob, then an inlineable sub springs into place:

```
package Foo;
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $x = 7;
BEGIN { $Foo::{GetX} = \$x }  # don't try this at home
say GetX; #=> 7
$x = 3;
say GetX; #=> 3
```

This currently works on most of my installed perl versions (5.14, 5.22, 5.24, 5.26). However, my 5.22-multi and 5.26-multi die with “Modification of a read-only value attempted”. This is not a problem for the constant module since it makes the reference target readonly first and (more importantly) never modifies that variable.

**So not only doesn't this work reliably, this will also completely mess up constant folding.**

---

If the function call overhead is indeed unbearable (e.g. takes a double-digit percentage of your processing time), then **doing the inlining yourself in the source code is going to be your best bet**. Even if you have a lot of call locations, you can probably create a simple script that fixes the easy cases for you: select all files that import your module and only have a single `package` declaration. Within such files, replace calls to `GetABC` (with or without parens) to fully qualified variable accesses. Hopefully that token is not mentioned within any strings. Afterwards, you can manually inspect the few remaining occurrences of these calls.

Comment: Thanks for the very good answer. My 5.12.3-multi doesn't allow writing that variable either... I tried several hours with different things now without any luck. Search&Replace the method call in all packages is the best answer here (at least for now)